# Why won't this load storyboard event in WPF not fire?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Ok for some reason I've set up an event trigger for window.loaded in WPF to fire the AnimationBoard storyboard but for some reason it doesn't want to load.  Any ideas out there?  Thanks!  Below is the code:

---

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Class="CFPSite.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800" Height="600" Background="Black" mc:Ignorable="d">

<Window.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationBoard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="6.667"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5250000" Value="71.333"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.8000000" Value="-176.167"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="11.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-4.666"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5250000" Value="-130.666"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.8000000" Value="-114.166"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="23.834"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="29.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="-1.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="1.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)">
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="0.484,2.565"/>
        </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="70.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="-3"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="29.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContactUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="144"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContactUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContactUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="29.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContactUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FAQ" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="225"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FAQ" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FAQ" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FAQ" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8000000" Value="29.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="EnlargeText">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="32"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="37.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="White"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkText">

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="37.33"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="32"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutUs" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="White"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ServicesEnlargeText">

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="32"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="37.333"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">

            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="White"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="-9.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ServicesShrinkText">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontFamily)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Fonts/#Calibri</FontFamily>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontSize)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="37.33"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="32"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Services" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="White"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="800" Height="600" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-8,-20,-8,-16" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Margin="200,3.493,165.14,29.507" Source="dollarladder.jpg" Stretch="Fill" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253.167" Height="193.96" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontFamily="Fonts/#Calibri" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="Financial Planning, it's not merely a way of getting rich. It's a delicate balance of building trust in the clients, working your way up gradually through various ladders of wealth and property.  Occasionally one may stumble but the end result will ultimately be with enough perseverance, one will reach the top." TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="1.381"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AboutUs" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,46,67,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="46" Text="About Us" TextWrapping="Wrap" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:IsLocked="True">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Services" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,46,67,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="46" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:IsLocked="True"><TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform><Run Text="Services"/><LineBreak/><Run Text=""/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ContactUs" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,46,67,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="46" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextWrapping="Wrap"><TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform><Run Text="Contact Us"/><LineBreak/><Run Text=""/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="FAQ" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,46,67,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="46" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="FAQ" d:IsLocked="True"><TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform></TextBlock>
</Grid>
<Window.Triggers>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="AboutUs">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EnlargeText_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkText}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="AboutUs">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EnlargeText_BeginStoryboard1" Storyboard="{StaticResource EnlargeText}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="Services">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShrinkText_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ServicesEnlargeText}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="Services">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ServicesShrinkText_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ServicesShrinkText}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimationBoard}"/>
    </EventTrigger>

</Window.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, had to rebuild the animation, not exactly sure what caused this however.